# Outlook 2011 for Mac will not show main screen

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011, osx-yosemite

For some reason my outlook inbox window is not showing. When I select show all from the menu it looks like it is trying to show the window in full screen however the screen just shows blurred background. I tried to rebuild the database as some suggested, to restart etc. to no avail.

I use dual screens with my  MBP and I wonder if the screens last known position got saved in a wrong way and can restore it in the visible area.

Any ideas on how to fix this are greatly appreciated.

Mac OS is Yosemite, the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in earlier versions of Mac OS Yosemite. But try downloading the latest version of Yosemite, released on Tuesday. Looks like the Outlook problem is fixed.